# How to use a maven package as both a dependency and a plugin

Tags: maven, junit, tomcat7

I am putting together a new project using Maven and JUnit. I am using the t7 plugin to run the application under tomcat after maven has compiled and run tests. I didn't have any problems until I wanted to set up the javaURLContextFactory in a JUnit test. The javaURLContextFactory is in the t7 plugin, but not in any of the dependencies for the project. With the plugin only defined as a plugin, the JUnit test fails, as it can't find the javaURLContextFactory class. If add the plugin as a dependency only, The JUnit test works, bu then it can't find the plugin when I want to run or debug. If I define it in both, I get bizarre errors related to parsing the web.xml.

Here is my current pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.star2star</groupId>
    <artifactId>distribute</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.8.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>distribute Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0-rc1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>distribute-v1</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.t7mp</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-t7-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.10.M8</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is there any way to reference the classes in the plugin as a dependency, or reference the dependency as a plugin? Is there some other method of fixing this?

Comment: Never use a maven-plugin as a dependency, cause it should be placed in the build area but in this case better a [pluginManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) part. Have you tested your build on command line via **mvn clean package**?

Comment: @khmarbaise I noticed the plugin as a dependency was a bad thing. The pluginManagement was interesting, but I don't see how it applies to a single pom.xml. Doing mvn clean package had the same issue, it couldn't find javaURLContextFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution after talking to a co-worker.

By including the plugin as a dependency, I know it's bad, and setting the scope to **provided**, it was available for the JUnit test, but not included in the war when it was deployed using the t7 plugin. Then the unit tests were able to run, with the javaURLContextFactory and it still deployed properly.